# Running custom command on folder

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I wanted to ask about running custom commands in command line.
I have win 7 with Node.js and grunt installed.

Now, when i want to run grunt.js on some folder, i must:

```
run cmd.exe
```

in cmd type for example:

```
d:/
cd xampp/htdocs/project/app/webroot/
grunt
```

This will run grunt tasks on this folder, but i change projects often, and always need to type this.

Is there a way to create some kind of shortcut for this?

Comment: Add the Grunt executable's location to your PATH environment variable. And/or make batch files.

Answer (score 0):

From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
Finally, in the Environment Variables window (as shown below), highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon